# Convert List of bytes to List of objects using automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a source object which contains a list of bytes property('Roles')

Source object:

```
public class SourceObjectModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<byte> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

And the destination object contains a list of objects property ('Roles')

Destination object:

```
public class DestinationObjectModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<MyObject> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

MyObject object:

```
public class MyObject
{                
    public byte Id { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to map source object to destination object.

My automapper configuration:

```
o.CreateMap<SourceObjectModel, DestinationObjectModel>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))                                                                                
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Roles, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => new MyResolver()))
```

I created a custom converter class to convery list of bytes to list of objects.

MyResolver class:

```
public class MyResolver: ITypeConverter<List<byte>, List<MyObject>>
{
    public List<MyObject> Convert(List<byte> source, List<MyObject> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return new List<MyObject>();
    }
}
```

My app is crashing after running AssertConfigurationIsValid(), but I do not get a specific detailed error. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my custom resolver class?

Comment: `AssertConfigurationIsValid` does provide information about the issue.  It throws either a `AutoMapperConfigurationException` or an `AggregateException`.  In the latter case, you have to look at its inner exceptions.

Comment: I get the following error: 'Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.'

Comment: Look in the inner exceptions then.

Comment: It is the same no more details about the error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have managed to fix the error. A added a new mapper inside my mapper configuration:

```
o.CreateMap<List<byte>, List<MyObject>>()
                 .ConvertUsing<MyResolver>();
```

And I removed the property mapping from the base source object to destination object mapping configuration:

```
o.CreateMap<SourceObjectModel, DestinationObjectModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id));
```